# Invalid syntax error. Maybe my operator?

Tags: python

Why won't this work? I keep messing around with my if statement and it keeps giving me an error and saying invalid syntax. Maybe I just forgot how to set up the operator. Please be gentle, i'm just starting to switch over from Java to Python. Thanks!

```
# Create a short program that gets a users age and name

print("Hello there! What is your name?")
myName = raw_input()
print("Okay then %s(myName) how old are you?")
myAge = raw_input()
if myAge < 18
    print("Ah, so you're an adult then!")
else if age >= 18
    print("So you're a kid, huh?")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've got a few problems:

- `if myAge < 18` and `else if age >= 18` should both have colons at the end of the line.
- `else if` should be `elif`.
- Your age comparison is backwards.
- Your `myAge` variable isn't an integer. It's a string.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
myName = raw_input("Hello there! What is your name? ")
myAge = int(raw_input("Okay then {0} how old are you? ".format(myName)))

if myAge >= 18:
    print("Ah, so you're an adult then!")
else:
    print("So you're a kid, huh?")
```

If you're using Python 3, change `raw_input` to `input`.

Comment: @Blender If you wouldn't mind linking or explaining something to me, I would be appreciative. I've always thought in order to print out a stored variable in a string in Python you have to do something along the lines of "%s" or "%d", etc. What is that "{0}" that you used?

Comment: @Xiam: That's the new string formatting syntax. `'{0} {1} {0}'.format('a', 'b')` will return `a b a`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if myAge < 18
```

is missing the colon at the end

```
if myAge < 18:
             ^
             |
```

and consider using `elif` in place of `else if`. Either way, that also need a `:` at the end, so

```
elif age >= 18:
              ^
              |
```

Blender points out some other problems, like your "backward" age comparison, and the need to convert the string you receive as input to a number before you make your comparison.

Answer (score 1):

@Xiam: I am also new to Python and I find the language "amazing". To add some more info to the other answers, all Control Flow statements in Python like if-else, for, while needs to have a trailing colon (:). This is a way to tell the interpreter that the lines of code that follow begin to a new block of statements and might be executed depending on the outcome of the Control Flow statement preceding it. Hope it helps.